# javascript - Alert not working in IE 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, alert, onsubmit

In my web-application I have added javascript in a jsp file.
The alert message is popping up in Firefox. But the alert window is not working in IE 8. Following is the javascript that I am using.
Can anyone please tell how to make this work in IE 8?

```
 function doSubmit() {
        var checkbox = document.getElementById("terms");
        if (!checkbox.checked) {
          alert("error message goes here.");
          return false;
      } else {
      return true;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Nothing looks wrong with the code you've posted.  Do you see errors in the browser console?

Comment: Where is `doSubmit()` called from?

Comment: alert window is not popping whien the checkbox is not checked.(in IE 8 )

Comment: post some more code, where do you call this?

Comment: @nnnnn - **<form name="f" action="${fn:escapeXml(form_url)}" method="POST" onsubmit="return doSubmit()" >**

Comment: @ngmiceli - that's not going to help much for the IE8 problem.

Comment: @user1351052 - can you post a simple Fiddle or JSBin demonstrating the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine, here is how you use it!

```
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function doSubmit() {
        var checkbox = document.getElementById("vehicle");
        if (!checkbox.checked) {
          alert("error message goes here.");
          return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

</script>
</head>

<body>

    <form name="frm1" onsubmit=" return doSubmit()">
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" />Checked<br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

added correction as suggested.

Comment: It would need to be `onsubmit="return doSubmit()"` if an error condition is supposed to actually stop the form submitting. (And that's what the OP _is_ doing, according to a comment above.)